# Populating Redux-Form with initial values from Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

For the life of me, I cannot get my Redux-Form to populate with initial values. I feel like I have looked at every SO question/answer out there, but nothing has helped me as of yet.

Here are some relevant sections of my code:

```
class Profile extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          <Field type="text" name="firstName" label="First Name" component={rfField} />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      firstName: state.getIn(['user', 'firstName'])
    }
  };
};

const profileForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'profile',
  enableReinitialize: true
})(Profile);

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps);
const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'profile', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'profile', saga });

export default compose(withReducer, withSaga, withConnect)(profileForm);
```

The state has the value I am fetching from it in `mapStateToProps`, however the field does not show the initial value; it remains empty. If I change `state.getIn(...)` to just the literal 'test', the field remains empty. If I move `initialValues` to the `reduxForm(...)` invocation, using just 'test' instead of `state.getIn(...)`, the `firstName` field properly shows 'test'.

I theorize it has something to do with the way I am using the `reduxForm`, `connect`, and `compose` functions. This is the way the react-redux-boilerplate project is set up, so I am just using that paradigm.

I definitely am not a React/Redux expert, so please let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks!

From package.json:

```
react: 16.4.0
redux: 4.0.0
react-redux: 5.0.7
redux-form: 7.4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED AGAIN!

Since it appears that `mapStateToProps` is being set asynchronously, you'll need to use React `state` in combination with `this.props.initialize()` within the `componentDidUpdate` method.

The `this.props.formFields` (or whatever you name it in `Redux` state) needs to follow the same naming convention specified in the `Field`'s `name`. For example: `{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }` should match `<Field name="firstName" ... />` `<Field name="lastName" .../>`.

You will also need `keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true` if you plan on allowing the user to edit the input -- otherwise, despite what the input shows, it'll submit the initialized value.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zm3mqw2m4

The example below fires a Redux action (`this.props.asyncFormFields`) in the class's `componentDidMount` method, shows a spinner, then checks if `this.props.formFields` has been changed in the class's `componentDidUpdate` method. If `this.props.formFields` was changed, it sets `this.state.isLoading` to `false`, then prompts the Redux Form fields to be initialized with `this.props.formFields` data.

**SimpleForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { asyncFormFields } from "../actions";
import ShowError from "../components/ShowError";
import ShowForm from "../components/ShowForm";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";

class SimpleForm extends Component {
  state = {
    err: "",
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (this.props.formFields !== prevProps.formFields) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false }, () =>
        this.props.initialize({ ...this.props.formFields })
      );
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = () => this.props.asyncFormFields();

  reinitializeForm = () =>
    this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => this.props.asyncFormFields());

  render = () =>
    this.props.err ? (
      <ShowError err={this.props.err} />
    ) : this.state.isLoading ? (
      <Spinner />
    ) : (
      <ShowForm {...this.props} reinitializeForm={this.reinitializeForm} />
    );
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "SimpleForm",
  enableReinitialize: true,
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true
})(
  connect(
    state => ({ err: state.server, formFields: state.fields }),
    { asyncFormFields }
  )(SimpleForm)
);
```

---

Another way to initialize a Redux form is to use ReduxForm's `formReducer` plugin. This is a bit more complex and involves more steps, but the outcome is the same:

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xppnmklm7q

**SimpleForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { asyncFormFields, initForm } from "../actions";
import ShowError from "../components/ShowError";
import ShowForm from "../components/ShowForm";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";

class SimpleForm extends Component {
  state = {
    err: "",
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (this.props.formFields !== prevProps.formFields) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false }, () => this.props.initForm(this.props.formFields));
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = () => this.props.asyncFormFields();

  reinitializeForm = () => this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => this.props.asyncFormFields());

  render = () =>
    this.props.err 
      ? <ShowError err={this.props.err} />
      : this.state.isLoading 
        ? <Spinner />
        : <ShowForm {...this.props} reinitializeForm={this.reinitializeForm} />
  );
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "SimpleForm",
  enableReinitialize: true,
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true
})(
  connect(
    state => ({ err: state.server, formFields: state.fields }),
    { asyncFormFields, initForm }
  )(SimpleForm)
);
```

**actions/index.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { INIT_FORM, SET_FORMFIELDS, SERVER_ERROR } from "../types";

export const asyncFormFields = () => dispatch =>
  axios
    .get("https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=us&results=1")
    .then(({ data: { results } }) =>
      dispatch({
        type: SET_FORMFIELDS,
        payload: {
          firstName: results[0].name.first,
          lastName: results[0].name.last
        }
      })
    )
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: SERVER_ERROR, payload: err }));

export const initForm = fields => ({ type: INIT_FORM, payload: fields });
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";
import { INIT_FORM, SET_FORMFIELDS, SERVER_ERROR } from "../types";

const fieldsReducer = (state = {}, { payload, type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case SET_FORMFIELDS:
      return { ...state, ...payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const serverResponseReducer = (state = "", { payload, type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case SERVER_ERROR:
      return (state = payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const formReducers = {
  form: formReducer.plugin({
    SimpleForm: (state, { payload, type }) => { // <----- 'SimpleForm' - name given to reduxForm()
      switch (type) {
        case INIT_FORM: // <----- action type triggered by componentDidUpdate from 'SimpleForm'
          return {
            ...state, // <----- spreads out any previous form state (registered fields)
            values: {
              ...payload // <----- initializes form fields values from supplied initForm action 'field' values
            }
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
  })
};

export default combineReducers({
  fields: fieldsReducer,
  server: serverResponseReducer,
  ...formReducers
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt!  Using `this.props.initialize(...)` got me closer, but not quite there yet.  Could you explain why it is necessary to use that function?  My form seems extremely simple, so it is curious why it doesn't seem to work like all the other examples out there.  Additionally, at the time `componentDidMount()` is called in the lifecycle, it doesn't look like the component props are populated yet via `mapStateToProps`, as the value is undefined.  However, if I do something to cause a re-render, they appear.

Comment: Updated answer to include an asynchronous `mapStateToProps` example.

Comment: Updated answer again to include yet another approach to initialize a form via ReduxForm's `formReducer` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a sample with Redux-form for something else this week and had a thought. For my form I was also using redux form with the wizard functionality and it was not retaining state (even with the `destroyOnUnmount: false`). To fix it I took out the wizard functionality and used just one form (wizard uses multiple forms) and did a hide and show of the questions themselves. Something tells me the issue lies with the multiple forms not keeping state. code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import injectReducer from '../../utils/injectReducer';
import injectSaga from '../../utils/injectSaga';
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchQuestions } from './actions';
import reducer from './reducer';
import saga from './sagas';
import QuestionForm from './QuestionForm';
import { addAnswer } from './actions';

export class Quiz extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.submitQuiz = this.submitQuiz.bind(this)
    // this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      page: 1,
      sendToSummary: false,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.props.fetchQuestions(resolve, reject);
      this.props.addAnswer();
    }).catch((error) => {
      throw new SubmissionError(error);
    })
  }
  submitQuiz() {
    console.log("sub");
    this.setState(() => ({
      sendToSummary: true
    }))
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.props, "test");
    const { page } = this.state;
    const { questions } = this.props
    return (
      <div className="quiz-form">
       {questions ? 
          <QuestionForm 
            onSubmit={this.submitQuiz} 
            // previousPage={this.previousPage}
            questions={questions}
          />
         : 'loading'}
        {(this.state.sendToSummary === true) ? <Redirect to='/summary' /> : null}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapSateToProps(state){
  console.log(state)
  return {
    form: state.get('form'),
    questions: state.getIn(['questionSet', 'questions'])
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchQuestions: () => dispatch(fetchQuestions()),
  addAnswer: () => dispatch(addAnswer()),
})

const withReducer = injectReducer({key: `questionSet`, reducer});
const withSaga = injectSaga({key: `questionSet`, saga});
const withConnect = connect(
  state => mapSateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
);

export default compose(
  withReducer, 
  withSaga, 
  withConnect,
)(Quiz);
```

this is the form:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RadioButton from '../../components/RadioButton';
import { Field, reduxForm, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import { Button, Form } from 'reactstrap';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
import { addAnswer } from './actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Progress from '../../components/Progress';

class QuestionForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedValues:[],
      isChecked: true,
      currentQuestion: 0
    };
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);

  }
  nextPage(){
    if(this.state.currentQuestion !== this.props.questions-1){
      this.setState({ currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion + 1 })
    }
  }
  previousPage(){
    if(this.state.currentQuestion !== 0){
      this.setState({ currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion - 1 })
    }
  }
  render(){
    const { handleSubmit, questions } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props.questions)
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="quizForm">
        {questions.map((question,i) => {
          console.log(i, this.state.currentQuestion)
          return (
            <div key= {`question-${i}`} className={this.state.currentQuestion === i ? '':'d-none'}>
              <h1>{ question.category }</h1>
              <h2>{ ReactHtmlParser(question.question) }</h2>
              <RadioButton name={`question-${i}`} label="true" radioButtonValue={true} />
              <RadioButton name={`question-${i}`} label="false" radioButtonValue={false} />
              <Button type="button" onClick={this.previousPage} className="next">
                Previous
              </Button>
              {this.state.currentQuestion === questions.length-1 ? <Button type="submit" className="next" onClick={() => this.nextPage(i)}>
                Submit
              </Button>: <Button type="button" className="next" onClick={() => this.nextPage(i)}>
                Next
              </Button>}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      <Progress page={this.state.currentQuestion + 1} total={10}/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  console.log(state)
  return {
    form: state.get('form'),
    questions: state.getIn(['questionSet', 'questions'])
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchQuestions: () => dispatch(fetchQuestions()),
  addAnswer: () => dispatch(addAnswer()),
})

QuestionForm = connect(state => (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(QuestionForm)

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'quiz_form',
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  // forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
  // keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true
})(QuestionForm);
```