# Redux Form - Initializing state with dynamic field names

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm having some issues trying to set a default value for some fields on my form.  The problem I'm having is that since its inside of a .map function I need to have dynamic field names and don't know how I should name it when I try using `intializeValues` in my `mapStateToProps.

My Field Array is also inside a FormSection in the parent component.

The field i'm trying to set a default value for.

```
{fields.map((table, index) =>

  <Field
    name={`${table}.leftStile`}
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="leftStile"
  />
}
```

The parent component with redux

---

```
 <FormSection name="dimensions">
   <OrderTable />
 </FormSection>
```

---

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  form: state.form,
  submitted: state.Orders.submitted,
  initializeValues: {
  //problem naming here <-----
  }
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  addDoorOrder
}, dispatch);

DoorOrders = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(DoorOrders);

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'Orders',
  enableReinitialize: true
})(DoorOrders);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540678/populating-redux-form-with-initial-values-from-redux-store/52542823#52542823

Comment: i dont think so - that doesn't use .map - im talking about mapping through an array with dynamic field names. his field is just a simple "firstName" - my field name is in array . name={`${table}.leftStile`}

Answer (score 0):

I will update the answer if you can also provide the presentational component `DoorOrders`. And the shape or an example of the `fields` prop.
For now, I will assume that `fields` is a `DoorOrders` prop, does not come from `redux` and has a shape like:

```
[
    { leftStile: "firstName", initialValue: "John" },
    { leftStile: "lastName", initialValue: "Doe" },
    //...
]
```

**You can access these props inside a `mapStateToProps` function as the second argument**:

```
import { fromPairs } from "ramda"

//...

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
   form: state.form,
   submitted: state.Orders.submitted,
   initializeValues: R.fromPairs( // <= see below
       ownProps.fields.map(table => [table.leftStile, table.initialValue])
   )
});

//...
```

I'm using [ramda's `fromPairs`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#fromPairs) to transform `[[a, b], [c, d]]` into `{ a: b, c: d }` because I love it but other libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#fromPairs) can achieve this (or vanilla javascript).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Fields is actually from Field Array in redux form (https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/fieldarray.md/).  OrderTable is a component which holds the order table.  DoorOrders is just the parent component that holds the different forms and handles the submission.  I just updated my post to show the FormSection component that holds the OrderTable component.  I'll try the fromPairs and see if that works!  Thank you!

Comment: I tried using ramda - but i keep getting undefined errors.  R is undefined, map as well.  I wish there was just a way to set default value on the Field component without all this hassle.